# How to call info that is different, but in the same column based on a type designation in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like below:

[image: Driver-Tractor]

It is a Driver ID and Tractor (Truck) ID under Equipment_ID with Equipment_Type D = driver and T = Tractor both associated to a Movement ID.

I would like to be able to say that if Equipment Type = 'D' then Equipment_ID = kimjames and if Equipment_Type = 'T' then 49085 but I am unsure how to do this in sql while being nested within a select or as a where nested within another Where statement.

This is in a larger query where the tables are joined by Movement ID. There are also many many more entries in the table, this is just a sample of the data I'm dealing with.

Here is the query I'm working with atm:

```
select distinct
    Movement.ID as 'Movement ID',
    Tractor.ID as 'Tractor',
    Driver.ID as 'Owner',
    Payee.Legal_Name as 'Name',
    Driver.Payee_ID as 'Team Driver',
    sum(Movement.Move_Distance) as 'Total',
    Driver.Type_of as 'Driver Type'

from
    Driver
full outer join
    Continuity on Continuity.Equipment_ID = Driver.ID
full outer join
    Movement on Movement.ID = Continuity.Movement_ID
full outer join
    Tractor on Tractor.ID = Continuity.Equipment_ID
inner join
    Payee on Payee.ID = Driver.ID

where 
    Driver.Company_ID = 'TMS'
    and Driver.Is_Active ='Y'
    and Driver.Type_of ='C'
    and Movement.Company_ID = 'TMS'
    and Movement.ID = Continuity.Movement_ID
    and Continuity.Equipment_Type_ID = 'D'
    and Driver.ID = Continuity.Equipment_ID
    and Continuity.Company_ID = 'TMS'
    and Xfer2settle_date between '03/18/2016' and '03/30/2016' 

group by
    Movement.ID,
    Tractor.ID,
    Driver.ID,
    Payee.Legal_Name,
    Driver.Payee_ID,
    Movement.Move_Distance,
    Driver.Type_of

order by Driver.ID
```

Currently when I run this I get no Tractor Information because if I try to add:

```
and Continuity.Equipment_Type_ID = 'T'
and Tractor.ID = Continuity.Equipment_ID
```

to the Where conditions then it conflicts with:

```
and Continuity.Equipment_Type_ID = 'D'
and Driver.ID = Continuity.Equipment_ID
```

and I already have Tractor.ID = Continuity.Equipment_ID in the Join.

Not sure how to code it in order for it to pull the tractor ID's from the Continuity table which the sample is from.

The only columns pulling from the continuity table are the 2nd and 3rd, but results would look something like this for a single row:

[image: 2]

Comment: Perhaps you need to more clearly explain your requirements here. How about a little bit more sample data and an explanation of the output?

Comment: Yea what exactly are you trying to find out? From what I can tell you most likely want a case statement but I'm not sure what output you are trying to reach.

Comment: Added some more info ... was trying to stay simple with my question but prolly more detail is better. XD

Comment: You could create a derived table for continuity doing a self join to get both records on one line (assuming there are no more than two types...)  `SELECT C1.Movement_ID as C_Movement_ID, C2.Driver_ID FROM continuity C1 LEFT JOIN Continuity C2 on C1.Movement_ID = C2.MovementID and C1.Equipment_Type = 'T' and C2.Equipment_Type = 'D') as C3`  and then C3 contains both the equipment and river for a given movement on one line. which can be joined back in.. But I'm not sure that's what you're after post expected results for your sample data it would help clarify question and add more data to sample.

Comment: That seems like a feasible idea, but I am not sure how adverse that would be to query times against the DB. Also added a sample result that I'd be looking for to the end of the post.

Comment: I guess this wouldn't give me any trouble outside of the fact that the way the data is stored in the table is weird rather than being column separated ... its row separated and identified by another column... makes it more difficult to figure out the logic to pull the data I want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
where ( (Equipment_Type = 'D' and Equipment_ID = 'KIMJAMES') or
        (Equipment_Type = 'T' and Equipment_ID = '49085')
      )
```

Comment: There are other entries in there other than that one Driver and Tractor. Wouldn't that only give me that specific ID for each one and no others and I'd literally have to go in and do it for each one manually which defeats the purpose a little. Not sure.

Sorry if my post was a little vague. I edited it and added some context.

Comment: @JacobHyde . . . "I would like to be able to say that if Equipment Type = 'D' then Equipment_ID = kimjames and if Equipment_Type = 'T' then 49085".  If you have another question, then ask it as *another* question.